# number of ways in which player gets his cards

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Two different packs of cards are shuffled together. Cards are dealt equally among 4 players, each getting 13 cards. The number of ways in which a player get his cards if no two cards are from same suit with the same denomination

i don not know how to begin

thanks

Comment: How many ways can a player get their first card? Given that card, how many ways can a player get their second card? and so on. Then multiply.

Comment: @Henry i think first card can be drawn to player A in 2 . 52 ways.

Comment: and the second (knowing the first)?

Comment: @Henry 2 . 50 ways ???

Comment: why not $2 \times 51$?

Comment: @Henry i have almost followed up on this. idea is that cards decrease by 2 as chosen card is eliminated from both packs for next selection but i do not understand as to why Robert Z(answer below) divided by 13!

Answer (score 1):

A hand of 13 cards out of 52 (4 suits multiplied by 13 denominations) can be given in $\binom{52}{13}=\frac{52\cdot 51\cdots 40}{13!}$ ways. Now consider that each one of those 13 cards can be of the first pack or the second pack (2 ways). So the number of ways is 
$$\binom{52}{13}\cdot 2^{13}=\frac{104\cdot 102\cdots 82\cdot 80}{13!}.$$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58342/discussion-on-answer-by-robert-z-number-of-ways-in-which-player-gets-his-cards).

Answer (score 0):

Think about it first as if you distribute one pack and then the other. 
First pack has N cards. For the first person you have N cards to distribute. Then, next person will have a choice of N-1 cards to distribute, next N-2... etc. So this involves N!. Try to continue from there maybe?